# Embed an HTML table populated by an API inside a Blazor app

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I made an additional link in a Blazor app I'm testing with.

It is inside my NavMenu.razor file and looks like this:

```
    <li class="nav-item px-4">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="react-table">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Goto Table
        </NavLink>
    </li>
```

The problem is, I need an HTML table that is dynamically populated with data from an API.

Is something like that possible with Blazor or would I have to use some other technology such as React?

Thanks

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks, I just looked at it, but it looks like just static data.  Not data retrieved from an API.

Comment: Oh I see, the randomized data.  :) But I guess I mean, in React, I would use something like this to get data: axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);  But I can't find anyway to do that in Blazor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm sorry for another question, but can you do with Server side Blazor too or must you use the client side?

Comment: NavMenu.razor is a part of your shared layout so you can write a JavaScript function for your API connection and keep it alive with a timer, then make a reference to this .js file in your _Host.cshtml